# ROR + Passenger: Memory consumption

Tags: ruby, phusion-passenger

I am optimizing my VPS where I unfortunately have to run ROR under passenger.
I've set it up so that it shutdown all application instances after 1 minute idle time, but there is still substancial amount of memory consumed by the following parts, which are running forever:

```
23716 www-data  20   0 75300  60m 2384 S    0 15.2   0:03.15 ruby1.8
23712 root      20   0 30584  19m 2424 S    0  4.8   0:01.20 ruby1.8
23675 root      20   0 15872 6340 1572 S    0  1.6   0:00.47 ruby1.8
23678 nobody    20   0 10476 3036 2484 S    0  0.7   0:00.00 PassengerLoggin
23673 root      20   0 14172 1964 1728 S    0  0.5   0:00.02 PassengerHelper
23670 root      20   0  5328 1604 1420 S    0  0.4   0:00.00 PassengerWatchd
```

Any suggestions on what can I do with them? ROR is rarely used, but due to these idle processes it eats like 25% of VPS RAM :-(

PS. I've already switched to Enterprise edition of ruby to try to reduce memory consumption....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PassengerPoolIdleTime 300
RailsFrameworkSpawnerIdleTime 1800
RailsAppSpawnerIdleTime 600
```

By default Passenger is using the above values. You can add those lines into the passenger part of your Apache conf and try tweaking the values.